# If $a^{8}+a^{7}-a^{5}-a^{4}-a^{3}+a+1= mn$ then $m\equiv n\equiv 1 \pmod{15}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How to prove: in integers for any $a$

If

$$a^{8}+a^{7}-a^{5}-a^{4}-a^{3}+a+1= mn,$$

then

$$m\equiv n\equiv 1 \pmod{15}.$$
?

Answer (score 3):

The only trick is that
$$a^8+a^7-a^5-a^4-a^3+a+1=\Phi_{15}(-a)$$
where $\Phi_{15}(x)$ is the cyclotomic polynomial:
$$\Phi_{15}(x)=\frac{(x^{15}-1)(x-1)}{(x^3-1)(x^5-1)}.$$
Assuming that $\Phi_{15}(x)\equiv 0\pmod{p}$, then $x$ is a primitive $15$-root of unity in $\mathbb{F}_{p}^*$. By the Lagrange theorem, that may happen only if $15\mid(p-1)$, or $p\equiv 1\pmod{15}$.

So we have that all the prime divisors of $mn$ are of the form $15k+1$, and this implies that both $m$ and $n$ are $\equiv 1\pmod{15}$.